# LNK2005 error, already defined: Possibly one definition rule violation?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, opengl, sdl-2

I searched and found various similar questions though I wasn't able to find a solution for my problem.
It's a SDL2 + OpenGL program, I can compile it with no problems in Linux using g++ 4.9.1 though not on  Windows (VS 2013).

I get errors like:

> Error  1   error LNK2005: "union SDL_Event e" (?e@@3TSDL_Event@@A) already defined in engine.obj   PATH_TO_PROJECT\main.obj    Game

for all the variables defined in the file **engine.h**:

```
//engine.h
#ifndef ENGINE_H
#define ENGINE_H

#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_opengl.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "player.cpp"

SDL_Event e;
bool running = true;
bool up = false, down = false, left = false, right = false;
bool attack = false;

player hero(20, 300, 50, 50, 10.0);  //x, y, lenght, height, speed

void init(char* title, int WIDTH, int HEIGHT);
void draw(SDL_Window* screen, SDL_GLContext context, int WIDTH, int HEIGHT);

#endif
```

**engine.cpp** consists of:

```
//engine.cpp
#include "engine.h"

void init(int WIDTH, int HEIGHT) {
    //BODY OF THE FUNCTION
}

void draw(SDL_Window* screen, SDL_GLContext context, int WIDTH, int HEIGHT) {
    //BODY OF THE FUNCTION
}
```

**main.cpp** is the only file that includes **engine.cpp**:

```
//main.cpp
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_opengl.h>
#include "engine.cpp"
#include <iostream>

#define WIDTH 800
#define HEIGHT 600

int main() {
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    STD::cout << "SDL started." << STD::endl;

    init(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    //Create the window
    SDL_Window *screen = SDL_CreateWindow("game title", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, WIDTH, HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
    SDL_GLContext context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(screen);

    draw(screen, context, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

I also get these:

> Warning    9   warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'msvcrt.lib' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library    PATH_TO_PROJECT\MSVCRTD.lib(cinitexe.obj)   Game
>
> Error  10  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SDL_main referenced in function _main    PATH_TO_PROJECT\SDL2main.lib(SDL_windows_main.obj)  Game
>
> Error  11  error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals   PATH_TO_PROJECT\Game.exe    Game

I can't really understand what is going on, specially since I can compile it on Linux, could someone please help me out?
The libraries are corrected linked, verified that. Also, if I put all the code in the main function and use only one file it compiles and runs with no problem.

Comment: why are you include SDL.h and SDL_opengl again in main?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `main.cpp` file should include `engine.h`, not `engine.cpp`.

Further, you do define the global `e` multiple times, in every translation unit that includes the `engine.h` header.  In the `engine.h` header declare it `extern` instead, which tells the compiler that `e` exists *somewhere* but doesn't actually define it:

```
extern SDL_Event e;
```

Then define it in only one translation unit; put this in `engine.cpp`:

```
SDL_Event e;
```

You need to do the same thing with all of the other global variables as well.  Note that you need to initialize them where you define them, so this goes in the header:

```
extern bool running, attack, up, down, left, right;
```

And this goes in `engine.cpp`:

```
bool running = true;
bool attack = false; /* and so on */
```

Comment: +1 but not only `e`. all variables in "engine.h" are defined twice, 1st in "engine.cpp" when include "engine.h", and the 2nd in "main.cpp" when fixed to include "engine.h", need to do what you said to all variables in the header.

Comment: @SHR Indeed, that's why I mentioned to fix that first. That fixes defining everything multiple times, then all that's left to fix is `e`.

Comment: Thank you very much, changes I made:
main now includes "engine.h" (sorry for this, so stupid), removed the SDL.h and SDL_opengl.h includes from main.cpp and added "extern" to all variables in engine.h but the problem still exists.
The errour about "e" has disappeared though, only showing "already defined in engine.obj" error for the boolean variables and the class object

Comment: @LuanCristianThums Right, I'm not sure why I missed those. You need to do the same thing with any global variable you want to be visible from different translation units: declare them all `extern` in the header, and actually define and initialize them in one translation unit (`engine.cpp` here). See my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you for your patience, doing that did solve most of the problems but I'm left with 2 errors:
Error 2 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SDL_main referenced in function _main 
and
Error 3 error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Comment: Ok, solved it! Looks like SDL_main.h has a #define main SDL_main, what was causing the problem mentioned on my last comment. Declaring main with the int argc, char *args[] parameters solved it, my game is running now, thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

You are getting these redefinition issues as you have included .cpp file in your main:-

```
#include "engine.cpp"
```

You should always include header files only. ( Also these header files should contain appropriate header gaurds ).